# I have troubles reconstructing decomposed tensor in matlab

Tags: multidimensional-array, matrix, sparse-matrix, matlab

We have a tensor in matlab of size 308 x 22 x 29 x 12 x 492020
It is pretty big. We did decomposition on it and it worked fine. Now we are trying to reconstruct it back to get some predictions. When we run it it crashes with out of memory when we do multiplication of the last dimension.

I was trying to flatten our tensor into a 2 x 2 matrix to make reconstruction easier. I cannot find a way to do it, i tried using reshape function in matlab with no success. So basically I want to know a way in matlab to convert (308 x 22 x 29 x 12 x 492020) tensor into 2D matrix.

Just to explain data a bit more. We have a database of users searching for a car to buy. We want to do recommendation model. We created a tensor with 5 dimansions: 308 (car models) x 22 (body types) x 29 (price category) x 12 (make year) x 492020 (users). We then run tensor decomposition and we can now do clustering on the last decomposed dimension to group users by their search adn build some search log dependencies. Up to here we are ok. Now we want to reconstruct tensor from its decomposed version to get some new records that will act as predictions. Given that tensor is huge, we need a way of flattening it to perform reconstruction, it would be good if someone could share some sample matlab code of how to do it, as I am relatively new to matlab. So I want to convert 5D tensor into 2D

Comment: That's 1.1e12 elements; if each is a double then that's 8TB of memory required.  I think it's safe to assume that this is not possible.

Comment: I doubt that you have a tensor.  I've never heard of one remotely close to that size.  What kind of transformation is that?

Comment: Of course it exists, we were able to even decompose it without any issue, took 2 minutes on high performance server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to reconstruct the whole tensor in order to estimate sample reconstruction error of the "clustered" users.  For instance you can sample individual users and compare the reconstructed slice and gather statistics as you go along.  Usually in machine learning you want to cross-validate your model by using "out of sample" - i.e. randomly partition the training set from the testing set.

I would observe that body type is an attribute of car model and that price is roughly a function of age (and condition) of each model .. so you don't really have independent enough dimensions in this case.

The reason your 492020 users fit into memory is probably because the tensor is sparse.  Recombining a decomposed tensor is generally dense (although reduced rank) unless you enforce sparsity upon the factors.  In any case, computations are much more efficient using the decomposed form.

I am worried about your "do clustering" step - Tucker decomposition is linear (like principal components), Non-Negative Tensor Factorisation is probably closer to what you want to do .. assign each user a non-negative mix vector of some "typical" preferences.  "Clustering" tends to imply hard-edged classification, rather than fuzzy.

Answer (score 2):

If you have your huge 5D tensor in MATLAB variable list and you are able to access individuals elements of it, say `MyTensor(123,17,15,4,123456)` then you can do it, if you have enough storage space. I don't have experience of handling of any data of that size, but if you can access it, then you can reconstruct it. If you write everything to disk element-by-element or slice-by-slice or n-dimensional hyperslice-by-hyperslice, to separate files with running numbers and then load and reconstruct your elements/slices/hyperslices from these files in correct order, then you'll have your 2D matrix. If element accessing works for your 5D tensor, I'd start by creating a small 5D matrix and converting it to 2D matrix to see that the dimensions go in the right order, using only accessing methods that work with your huge 5D tensor too. After that you could reconstruct your huge 5D tensor with exactly the same code.

Comment: +1 I agree. I think, the memory is not enough to have the two copies of the data together. So, first save it to disk (as binary for example). Then read it one by one. You know the order, so, put it to the proper location on the matrix.

Comment: Just to explain data a bit more. We have a database of users searching for a car to buy. We want to do recommendation model.

Comment: Given that tensor is huge, we need a way of flattening it to perform reconstruction, it would be good if someone could share some sample matlab code of how to do it, as I am relatively new to matlab. So I want to convert 5D tensor into 2D